# Magento 2 order grid custom mass action 404 page not found

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, order-grid, massaction

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
            <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
                <action name="order_mass">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_mass</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action name</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ordermass/massaction/massAction"/>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attention</item>
                                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to complete the selected row record?</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
            </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

> etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="ordermass" id="ordermass">
            <module name="Vendr_Modulename"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Controller/Adminhtml/MassAction/MassAction.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\MassAction;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

/**
 * Class MassDelete
 */
class MassAction extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{
    /**
     * @var OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $orderManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param Shipping $shippingHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }

    /**
     * Hold selected orders
     *
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
       echo 'Test';
    }
}
```

But I got a 404 page not found, any suggestion, please?

Comment: "ordermass/massaction/massaction" change path like this

Comment: @mahmoudismail your controller path is wrong. Please try this path : **"ordermass/massaction/massaction"**

Comment: same problem with me kindly answer if any of you found it!